# Android Taking Screenshots of device

Tags: android

First of all yes i know its not possible to code this in my app without root permission.
I need to take screen shot even outside my app without root.
 I just need to know if i can request Android os for me to take a screen shot for me via some **intent**.
I wont have much control over it but is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently do not exists intent for this.
You can see the documentation of [Intents broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#constants) by the system

Comment: Currently does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot in an instrumented test ("androidTest") using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation#takeScreenshot() for example:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().takeScreenshot();
```

This works outside the context of the app.  Not sure if it serves your particular purpose, but it's an option.